# Can PolymerElements' iron-menu-behavior,iron-selector,etc. components only used in child elements?

Tags: polymer-2.x

```
<iron-selector attr-for-selected="sname" selected="one">
  <div>
    <p sname="one">1</p>
    <p sname="two">2</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p sname="three">3</p>
    <p sname="four">4</p>
  </div>
</iron-selector>
```

I just find Polymers' official selector components like **iron-menu-behavior**,**iron-selector**..can be used in child elements.How about descendant elements?It's suitable too?

1. If can be used in descendant elements.How should I do?
2. If not.Has other advice about how to select descendant elements.

Comment: Have you tried any of your 2 points?

Comment: For first point, I still can not find a suitable official component to do this.But for the second point I just use `querySelectorAll('tagName')`,but I don't think it's a good method.